# How can I find an older version of pip that works with Python 2.7?

Tags: python, libraries, 20.10, pip

I am using Ubuntu 20.10 in a Virtual Box. By default, this version of Ubuntu has Python 3.8 but I managed to install Python 2.7 (I need it for a specific program that does not work with Python 3) and to set it as default. Now, I need to install the wxPython library. If I am not wrong, I first need to install the pip package. However, I read that the newest version (pip 21.0) no longer supports Python 2. So, what can I do to install an older pip version that is compatible with Python 2.7 and that will allow me to obtain the wxPython library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This guide](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-pip-on-ubuntu-20.04/) will show you how to do it (however, has to be updated for python 2.7). These are the necessary steps:

Start by enabling the universe repository:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
```

Update the packages index:

```
sudo apt update
```

Use curl to download the get-pip.py script (for python 2.7):

```
sudo curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/2.7/get-pip.py --output get-pip.py
```

Once the repository is enabled, run the script as sudo user with python2 to install pip for Python 2:

```
sudo python2 get-pip.py
```

Verify installation by running the following:

```
pip --version
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you so much! However, after the last passage, I got this:

DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 2.7 in January 2021. More details about Python 2 support in pip can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support pip 21.0 will remove support for this functionality.

This was expectable, since I know that Python 2.7 is old. Is this likely to give me problems in the future?

Comment: Well, python 2 reached EOL january last year. So yes it's outdated, and apps should generally be updated to use python 3. If this approach does not work, I think the only option would be to build an [older release of PIP from source](https://github.com/pypa/pip/releases/tag/20.3.4).

Comment: The problem is that I am doing some computational simulations for a science project and the program only works with Python 2.X (probably because it was written in 2015, if I recall). Thanks to your answer the installation of pip 20.3.4 was successfull, so I guess that is enough for now. While we are at it, is it a problem to ask you about a guide to install wxPython for this older version?

Comment: https://bootstrap.pypa.io/2.7/get-pip.py returns a 404 Not Found

Comment: If you read the guide, you would notice the link has been changed. The answer has now been edited, the link now is: https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/2.7/get-pip.py